# document.execCommand(“copy”) doesn't work while calling it from $(document).on("click") function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

This is my code

```
$(document).on('click', '.cpyButton', function (e){
     msg = $(this).attr('data-message');
     copyToClipboard(msg);
        
});

function copyToClipboard(text) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val(text).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

This code is not working but If I call copyToClipboard function with normal click function , It is working fine

Ex :

```
$('#saveDraft').on('click', function(e) {
    copyToClipboard("working");
})
```

I have a problem while working with **$(document)**

Comment: Your first bind is on element `.cpyButton`, while second one is on `#saveDraft`. Do you have `.cpyButton` element in page?

Comment: [Works just fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/8pq1mxy0/).

Comment: Yes , copyToClipboard() function also calling from it but document.execCommand("copy"); does not trigger

Comment: .cpyButton is append by ajax call

Comment: It works fine for me on Chrome 91 @SahanSiriwardana. I believe that copy only works when directly invoked by a user interaction (so not after the response of AJAX). Are you invoking it with a click, or are you invoking it dynamically via JavaScript?

Comment: Yes it invoking with a click, but that button appends to DOM by an AJAX call

Comment: Appending with AJAX [shouldn't make any difference](https://jsfiddle.net/2jbm8gk7/). There is some other detail missing here.